# C# and third party Controls Techniques

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been using kendo Ui for web controls. I have an requirement to apply filter on one column in the grid and that is Age. So, I searched out and I have taken that field for Int type and that was the solution of my problem. The filter works fine but whenever we blur outside the filter, it changes the value into decimal. Like 34.00 which is not required. I searched for this solution but I did not got it's solution. My problem is some what similar to this one.

http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/filter-value-formatting-issue.aspx

This is the property with which column og grid is bound :

```
{    
    public int Age { get; set; }
    //and in razor view , I have
    .Name("DataGrid")
    .Columns(columns => { columns.Bound(p => p.Age).Title("Age"); }
}
```

Comment: On grid filter popup is in inbuilt functionality and if you want to display value without decimal in grid so its possible.

Comment: Showing value in grid is not my problem. that is fine and working. Problem is whenever I enter value in the filter , after blur the value changes into decimal. Rest is all fine.

Comment: Age can not be in decimal. that's why it looks awkward.

Comment: This guy has also got same problemhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129199/changing-the-kendo-numeric-filter-format

Comment: Same Problem , here also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897222/how-to-change-kendo-grid-filter-format

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Try to modify the amount of filter textbox in below code.

```
$('k-widget,.k-numerictextbox').find('span').find('input:eq(0)').live("focus", function (e) {}
```